# Continuity of the linear transformation $T(x(t))=x'(t)+\int_0^t x(t)\,dt.$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=C^{1}[0,1]$ with $\|x\|=sup_{[0,1]}(x)+sup_{[0,1]}(x^{'})$ and $Y=C[0,1]$  with supremum norm. Let $$T(x(t))=x'(t)+\int_0^t x(u)\,du.$$ Then $T : X\rightarrow Y$ is

$A.$ Continuous but not closed.

$B.$ Not continuous but closed.

$C.$ Continuous and closed both.

$D.$ Not continuous and not closed.

Please check my calculation

$\|T(x)\|=\|x'+\int_0^t x(u)\,du\|= \sup\{ |x'+\int_0^t x(u)\,du|\}\leq \sup \{|x'|\} + \sup\{|\int_0^t x(u)\,du|\}\leq sup(x^{'})+sup(x(t))=\|x\|?$ Hence $T$ is bounded and so closed as continuous linear map from Banach space to Banach. Please suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes i edited ....thanks.....

Comment: This is not correct. The estimate $\sup \{|x'|\} \le \|x\|$ does not hold.

Comment: Are you considering $T : X \rightarrow Y$?

Comment: The problem really specified the suup norm on $C^1$? That's not the usual norm...

Comment: @HansEngler I am using $sup(f+g)\leq sup(f)+sup(g).$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Now i think its ok???

Comment: That's now the standard norm, yes. That's not "the sup norm". Yes, with that norm the things you say about $T$ are correct.

Comment: ok sir thanks a lot....

Comment: In your current version of the problem, yes, $T : X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and closed.

Comment: @TrialAndError Yes sir ...thank you....If you write the solution then it will be beneficial for me as well as for others also...thanks...

Comment: @neelkanth : I added an answer for you. If you need more detail, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The norms on your spaces $X=C^1[0,1]$ and $Y=C[0,1]$ are
\begin{align}
             \|x\|_{X} & = \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x'(t)|+\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x(t)| \\
             \|y\|_{Y} & = \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x(t)|.
\end{align}
Both $X$ and $Y$ are complete spaces.

The operator $T : X\rightarrow Y$ is bounded because
\begin{align}
    \|Tx\|_{Y} & \le \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x'(t)|+\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\left|\int_{0}^{t}x(u)du\right| \\
   & \le \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x'(t)| + \int_{0}^{1}|x(u)|du \\
   & \le \sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x'(t)| + \sup_{u\in[0,1]}|x(u)| = \|x\|_{X}.
\end{align}
Therefore, $T : X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous. $T$ is also closed because it is continuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precise time....